# intercepts and the implicit function theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Why are the intercepts and points of intersection trouble points with respect to the implicit function theorem? I've been trying to solve some questions to determine where on the set i can locally represent functions, and the intercepts keep on coming up and i keep on mkssing them